# This file is indented with 4 spaces instead of 2

Tags: webstorm

I have a download project, but its indented is 4 spaces, My WebStorm settings is 2 spaces, so there will be a this warning.

> This file is indented with 4 spaces instead of 2

[image]

Is there a way to format all the files in WebStorm?

---

**EDIT-1**

As all we know we can use <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to format current file, but how can we format all the files in project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps using the "reformat code" feature. I use this all the time on my Mac (Command-Option-L). It seems you can do this for an entire directory:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/reformatting-source-code.html#refromat